# how to load data in table and bind the same to view Model class in .net core mvc (without refreshing the page)

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, datatable, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to add data in table via server but unable to succeed. I tried many things but nothing worked. I'm getting the data from the server but unable to populate that in table.. can someone please help me out?
I'm getting this :
"DataTables warning: table id=particlarsTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1"

Let me explain my code first:
(In View)
When I click on "Add New Particular" button, bootstrap modal will popup with input fields, those fields will send to the server then again back to view and populate the table with the same data without refreshing the whole page.

I'm stuck on the last stage, I'm getting the data on UI/View in ajax success handler but unable to load that data in table.

> here is my view :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="createAdHocForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Select Flat</label>
                <select asp-for="AdHocInvoice.FlatRid" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Flats,"FlatRid","FlatNumber"))" class="form-control form-control-sm selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                    <option selected disabled value="">Select One</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-sm table-responsive-md nowrap w-100" id="particlarsTable">
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th>Particulars</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="bg-white">
            @foreach (var item in Model.AdHocInvoice.FlatInvoiceItems)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Particular</td>
                    <td>@item.Amount</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info" type="button" onclick="showParticularForm()">Add New Particular</button>
    <hr />
    <div class="row text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success mx-auto" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

> bootstrap modal to fill the table :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="particularWindow">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Invoice Items</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="particularForm">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Enter Particular</label>
                                <input id="particularName" name="particular" class="form-control form-control-sm" required />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <label>Amount</label>
                            <input id="particularAmount" name="amount" class="form-control form-control-sm" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success mt-4" id="btnParticularSubmit" type="button" onclick="addParticular()">Add</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Scripts:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/DataTables/datatables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#particlarsTable').DataTable();
    });

    function showParticularForm() {
        $('#particularWindow').modal('show');
    }

    function addParticular() {
        var particular = $('#particularName').val();
        var amount = $('#particularAmount').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/FlatInvoice/AddParticular',
            data: 'particular=' + particular + '&amount=' + amount,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#particlarsTable').DataTable().ajax.reload()
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

> Action Method on controller:

```
public JsonResult AddParticular(string particular, decimal amount)
        {
            _flatInvoiceViewModel.AdHocInvoice.FlatInvoiceItems.Add(new FlatInvoiceItem { Particular = particular, Amount = amount });
            return Json(_flatInvoiceViewModel);
        }
```

> Class/Model:

```
public class FlatInvoiceItem
    {
        public Guid FlatInvoiceItemRid { get; set; }
        public Guid FlatInvoiceRid { get; set; }
        public Guid FundRuleRid { get; set; }
        public string Particular { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

> NOTE: this code is in initial phase, I need that input data on server for further process(will add code later) so don't want to use `$.('#table_body_id').append("<tr>..</tr>");` type of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Firstly,`reload()` is used to send request back to the method which display the DataTable initially(e.g. name this method `Test`).

2.Secondly,From your `AddParticular` method,you just add a data to the list but the lifetime is just one request,so when you reload to `Test` method,the list **still** contains the **initial** data **without new data**.

**Conclusion:** I suggest that you could save data to database.And get data from database.

Here is a working demo about how to use DataTabale:

1.Model:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public AdHocInvoice AdHocInvoice { get; set; }
}
public class AdHocInvoice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<FlatInvoiceItem> FlatInvoiceItems { get; set; }
}
public class FlatInvoiceItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid FlatInvoiceItemRid { get; set; }
    public Guid FlatInvoiceRid { get; set; }
    public Guid FundRuleRid { get; set; }
    public string Particular { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Particular { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

2.View:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="createAdHocForm">
    <table class="table table-sm table-responsive-md nowrap w-100" id="particlarsTable">
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th>Particulars</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @*<tbody class="bg-white">
            @foreach (var item in Model.AdHocInvoice.FlatInvoiceItems)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td id="particular">@item.Particular</td>
                    <td id="amount">@item.Amount</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>*@   //DataTable no need to add this tbody
    </table>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info" type="button" onclick="showParticularForm()">Add New Particular</button>
    <hr />
    <div class="row text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success mx-auto" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //$('#particlarsTable').DataTable();
        $('#particlarsTable').DataTable({
            ajax: {
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                url: '@Url.Action("Test", "Home")',
            },
            columns: [
                { 'data': 'particular' },
                { 'data': 'amount' }
            ]
        })          
    });  
function showParticularForm() {
    $('#particularWindow').modal('show');
}
function addParticular() {
    var particular = $('#particularName').val();
    var amount = $('#particularAmount').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/AddParticular',  
        data: 'particular=' + particular + '&amount=' + amount           
    }).done(function (data) {
        $('#particularWindow').modal('hide');
        $('#particlarsTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();                  
    });
}
</script>
```

3.Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public HomeController(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {         
        return View();
    }
    public JsonResult Test()
    {
        var _flatInvoiceViewModel = _context.Test.Include(i=>i.AdHocInvoice)
            .ThenInclude(a=>a.FlatInvoiceItems).Where(i => i.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
        var list = new List<ViewModel>();
        foreach (var item in  _flatInvoiceViewModel.AdHocInvoice.FlatInvoiceItems)
        {
            var model = new ViewModel() { Amount = item.Amount, Particular = item.Particular };
            list.Add(model);
        } 
        return Json(new { data = list });
    }
    public void AddParticular(string particular, decimal amount)
    {
        var _flatInvoiceViewModel = _context.Test.Include(i => i.AdHocInvoice)
.ThenInclude(a => a.FlatInvoiceItems).Where(i => i.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
        _flatInvoiceViewModel.AdHocInvoice.FlatInvoiceItems.Add(new FlatInvoiceItem { Particular = particular, Amount = amount });
        _context.SaveChanges();

    }
```

4.Result:
[image]
Reference:

- https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59449895/11398810

Comment: Thank you so much for such detail explanation!